# Why do Sokka and Katara need Aang?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

In the episode Bato of the Water Tribe, Sokka and Katara tell Aang they have decided to stay with him rather than going to see their father becasue he needs them more. Then, Katara explains they need him too. In what ways do they need him? Do they need him more than they need their father?

Comment: Isn't the Avatar supposed to be a savior of the world? That's a pretty big need if you ask me!

Comment: Also they're children, and close friends. They need each other emotionally.

Comment: Thanks much for the answers! Really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Well, apart from them being friends, Katara needs Aang to get to the Northern Water Tribe to find a waterbending master.